# Getting error action_request_validation_exception while mapping new field in already exist Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add a new field to my already exist Elasticsearch index but I'm getting the below exception:

```json
{
  "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
  "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"
}
```

I'm using the below API

```json
PUT order/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "title":  { "type": "text"}
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of elasticsearch are you using ?

Comment: Elasticsearch version 6.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the mapping type to the `PUT` request, and modify the request as :

```
PUT order/{{mapping-type}}/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "title":  { "type": "text"}
  }
}
```